# Does grant ALTER imply grant EXECUTE to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, alter, sql-grant

I want a database user to have `ALTER` and `EXECUTE` permissions to a stored procedure. Do I need to grant those separately, or does granting `ALTER` allow the user to `EXECUTE` also?

e.g.

```
GRANT ALTER ON [STOREDPROC] TO [SP_USER];

GRANT EXECUTE ON [STOREDPROC] TO [SP_USER];
```

or just:

```
GRANT ALTER ON [STOREDPROC] TO [SP_USER];
```

(does ALTER imply EXECUTE?)

Thanks!

Comment: `Execute` permission is given on a stored procedure not on a table.

Comment: oops - yes, not TABLE, SP - do you know if ALTER is enough or I have to grant EXECUTE also?

Comment: No you would need to give Execute permission too, if you want user to be able to execute the procedure, Alter will only allow user to alter procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, `ALTER` does not imply `EXECUTE`.

Slightly longer answer: there's a chart that says what permissions imply other permissions. Check it out!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx